# ios enterprise developer account

Tags: ios, iphone

Yesterday we got the ios enterprise developer account. I successfully create Dev & inhouse/Adhoc certificates & App Ids (like generic com.company.*). I can create developer profile and Ad-hoc profiles. But when I am trying to create inHouse profiles, Apple developer portal always gives me message like

"No App IDs are available.
Click "Create App ID" to create an App ID. You need an App ID to configure a Provisioning Profile."

I did same steps work lot of time for different clients but I don't know why it is showing error now.

See below images for reference.

[image: Distribution certificate list]

[image: Trying here to create inhouse profile for distribution]

[image: Portal message to create certificate which already present]

[image]

Please let me know where I am missing.

Comment: Go to Identifiers -> select App IDs to create an App Id that you would like to use for creating provisioning profile

Comment: I have app id for both like developer and distribution

Comment: I have an Enterprise account, but when I look at App IDs (per our screen shot), there is no InHouse/Dev marking in a column. The only thing I can think of is your Team ID is not properly set on the App ID

Comment: This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DalwadiV/2e43760d973c1d2baada) is having step by step process for setting up AppID, profiles, certificates - for developer account. I think for enterprise account also, the process would be the same, as far as your question is concerned. You might want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I was using wildcard app id (com.yourcompany.*) which is not allowed for In-House distribution. :-(. But Ad-hoc is accepting wildcard bundle id.

Application specific app id is required for InHouse. like com.yourcompany.myapp.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The interface is rather confusing - it suggests there are __no__ App IDs rather than it can't find any non-wildcard App IDS.

Comment: It's even worse, as it will display only explicit app ids in the dropdown list, and the text above contains an explanation about wild card ids, which are not allowed for in house profiles (anymore?!)... Does someone have an official source for this change from apple? Didn't find one on the web -.-

Comment: @d4Rk no official change but officially documented here (point 5) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Comment: I noticed that this really seems to be the correct behaviour, but somehow we were able to use IAPs in an enterprise signed app, maybe this was actually a bug from apple, as sometimes we also experienced some strange behaviour there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just create an App ID as it is telling you to do.  You can see the App IDs link on the left hand side of your screenshots.

Comment: I have app id for both like developer and distribution

Comment: App IDs aren't tied to developer/distribution, however.  Are you confusing App IDs with Provisioning Profiles by chance?

Comment: I have 3 app id but still I am getting message to create new app id. I have updated original question reference picture for you.

Comment: @Manoj is right. I had the same issue. Nowhere in the UI does it say that wildcard App IDs cannot be used for In-House apps. It's rather confusing!