# Issues with saving an archive for Enterprise development

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I archive my project and attempt to save it for Enterprise Development, I get the following error:

> Wildcard App IDs can not be used to create In House provisioning profiles. Please use an Explicit App ID.

I have created an App Id in the developer portal with the bundle id of com.gasdcs.iCOOP and matched an In House Distribution profile with that App ID. In my XCode project and target I have changed the code signing identities to the iPhone Distribution for my enterprise account, and changed the provisioning profile to the one I created linked to the App ID I made.

I have tried so many separate combinations of things and still cannot get this sorted out.

I have also tried creating an entire new blank project from scratch and still get the same error. Here are the steps I took:

1. Create new App ID com.gasdcs.test
2. Create new distribution provisioning profile tied to com.gasdcs.test
3. Create new xcode project test on bundle com.gasdcs
4. Set all code signing identities to iPhone Distribution: My account in project and target
5. Set provisioning profile to the new one I had just created
6. Archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many SO posts regarding the same issue, like this:
1 [ios enterprise developer account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366150/ios-enterprise-developer-account)

> Application specific app id is required for InHouse. like com.yourcompany.myapp.

More SO posts here:
2 [XCode export app, wildcard error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421245/xcode-export-app-wildcard-error)

The answer is:

> I have seen an [announcement](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) on Apple Developer page. Apple's WWDR Certificate was expiring and newest one available on that page. I updated that certificate and it worked!

3 [Is it possible to generate Enterprise/In house Provisioning Profile of a wildcard AppID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311152/is-it-possible-to-generate-enterprise-in-house-provisioning-profile-of-a-wildcar)

Comment: I have seen all those threads and have tried all the things listed in each one, none of which have worked.

Comment: I went through these posts again, and the WWDR cert was up to date in my "login" section, but not present in the "system" section. Once I copied it over, that remedied my problem.

Comment: This wildcard app id error can have many reasons, whatever I was aware, I posted here, but one can find more and more!